# In Sitecores Advanced System Reporter is there a way to select all items in the report?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

In the Sitecore Advanced System Reporter module is there some way to select all items in the report?  I can only figure out how to select one item at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can hold down the control (add individual)and shift (select everything between) button to select items the same as you would in windows explorer.  I think there's a setting that says how many items to display per page (app_config/include/asr.config, i think) too to add more items to show per page.

Comment: When I hold down the Shift key it acts just like the CNTRL key.  It only selects one.  It does not select everything in between.